# Ruby array find duplicate elements in sub arrays and add elements

Tags: arrays, ruby, duplicates

Sorry for the less than clear question but I can't find a better way of asking...

I have an array

```
a=[[1,2], [3,4], [4,2], [2,1]]
```

I want to find subarrays with duplicate elements, in this case [1,2] and [4,2]

I'd like to add the duplicate elements together and create a new entry and deleting the 2 original subarrays.

Result...

```
a=[[5,2], [3,4], [2,1]]
```

Is that possible?

EDIT: Added some code and more details as to what I'm trying to accomplish

I'm pretty new to programming and like to challenge myself so I'm trying to code a 2d bin algorithm for creating cut sheets for kitchen cabinets... I'm a cabinet maker.

Here's what I've come up with so far... what I was asking about is in the split_sheet method. Basically in some instances I want to combine the remaining empty sheet sections that either have the same width or same length. There might be more situations where something similar is needed but so far that's all I've found.

I tried using map but I can't get it to work with floats so what I'm doing is comparing new sheet sections with existing ones to see if I find a match.

```
    def cut_sheet_layout_algorithm#(length, width)
        sort_by_length_width=@cabinet_cut_sheet.sort{|a,b| [b[3], b[2]]<=>[a[3], a[2]]}     # sort by length then width     
        parts_group_by_thickness=sort_by_length_width.group_by{|thickness| thickness[1]}.values # group by thickness

        def create_sheet(length, width, thick)#, @new_sheet, sheet_full)                # Creates sheet
        @sheet=[]; @sheet_free_space=[]; @sheet_coords=[]; @new_sheet=false; sheet_full=false
        @sheet.push(length, width, thick)
        @sheet_free_space.push([length, width])
        end

        def split_sheet(section_number, sheet_section, part_dimensions)
        if part_dimensions[0]<=sheet_section[0] && part_dimensions[1]<=sheet_section[1]
            new_section_a_width=sheet_section[0]-part_dimensions[0]
            new_section_b_length=sheet_section[1]-part_dimensions[1]

            new_section_a_dimensions=[part_dimensions[0], new_section_b_length]
            new_section_b_dimensions=[new_section_a_width, sheet_section[1]]

            @sheet_free_space.delete_at(section_number)

            @section_a_combined=@section_b_combined=false

            @sheet_free_space.each{|section|
            @section_a_0=new_section_a_dimensions[0]==section[0]
            @section_a_1=new_section_a_dimensions[1]==section[1]

            @section_b_0=new_section_b_dimensions[0]==section[0]
            @section_b_1=new_section_b_dimensions[1]==section[1]

            if @section_a_1==true || @section_b_1==true
                section[0]=new_section_a_dimensions[0]+section[0]
                @section_a_combined=true
            end

            if @section_a_0==true || @section_b_0==true
                section[1]=new_section_a_dimensions[1]+section[1]
                @section_b_combined=true
            end
            }

            @sheet_free_space << new_section_a_dimensions if new_section_b_length!=0 && @section_a_combined==false 
            @sheet_free_space << new_section_b_dimensions if new_section_a_width!=0 && @section_b_combined==false
        end
        end

        def does_part_fit(part_dimensions)
        section_number=0
        @sheet_free_space.each{|section|
            if part_dimensions[0]<=section[0] && part_dimensions[1]<=section[1]
            @part_fits=true
            sheet_section=@sheet_free_space[section_number]
            split_sheet(section_number, sheet_section, part_dimensions)

            break
            else
            @part_fits=false
            end

            section_number+=1               
        }
        end

        parts_group_by_thickness.each{|grouped_by_thickness|                    # iterate groups to create cut sheet lists according to sheet thickness
        sheet_thick=grouped_by_thickness[0][1]
        @new_sheet=true                                     # variable to check if new sheet , used to determine startx and starty
        number_of_parts=grouped_by_thickness.length
        grouped_by_thickness.delete_if do |part|                        # iterate parts of each sheet thickness group
            create_sheet(@sheet_size_length, @sheet_size_width, sheet_thick) if @new_sheet==true # create new sheet only if preceeding sheet is full
            part_dimensions=[part_length=part[2].to_l+@blade_kerf, part_width=part[3].to_l+@blade_kerf]

            does_part_fit(part_dimensions)

            if @part_fits==true     # delete part if placed
            true
            else
            @new_sheet=true                                     # variable to check if new sheet , used to determine startx and starty
            false
            end
        end
        }
    end # end cut_sheet_layout_algorithm
```

Feel free to criticize my code that's how I learn.

Comment: Maybe if you explain what the first and second number of each set represents?

Comment: Of course it is. Do you have any snippet or are you looking just for the solution?

Comment: Do `[5,2]` and `[2,1]` share 2 in common? Or are they not common because the 2 is in a different place? Are all arrays just number pairs?

Comment: It's a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve overall... long story short I'm trying to code a 2d bin packing algorithm... I'm using an array to keep track of 'empty space' dimensions. But some sometimes I'd like to combine the dimensions of 2 'empty spaces' to create 1. Christ I'm confusing myself!!

Comment: @tadman no they don't for the exact reason you mentioned, they're not in the same place.

Comment: Suppose `a = [[1,2], [2,3], [3, 4]]`. What do expect to be returned?

Comment: @CarySwoveland no change because there are no duplicates in the same place.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". SO is here to help debug problems with your code, not to write the code for you. Please show us the minimum code that demonstrates the problem you're having.

Comment: In that case (which is not made clear in the question), what about `a = [[1,2], [1,3], [4,3]]`?

Comment: @theTinMan thanks for the links... but I don't have any code for this particular problem I'm having ... I'm obviously having a hard time even explaining what I'm trying to do... not looking for anyone to write the code but a helping hand pointing me in the right direction. ;)

Comment: @CarySwoveland honestly haven't encountered that situation yet... but that's something I need to think about!

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of a tricky thing to do, but with [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html) you have a lot of tools at your disposal to help crack it.

Here's one approach:

```
a = [[1,2], [3,4], [4,2], [2,1]]

count = Hash.new(0)

a.map do |r|
  # Expand each entry of the form [1,2]
  # to [ [1,2], [[1,0],[2,1]]
  [ r, r.each_with_index.to_a ]
end.each do |r, p|
  # Tabulate how many of the number+position values occur
  p.each do |x|
    count[x] += 1
  end
end.select do |r, p|
  # Only select entries where all number+position values are unique.
  p.all? do |x|
    count[x] == 1
  end
end.map do |r, p|
  # Extract the original data
  r
end

# => [[3, 4], [2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but the following code compare the two arrays and remove the duplicates.

```
a=[[1], [2], [3], [4]]

b=[[1], [3]]

c = a - b

puts c
```

So you'd be wanting to do something similar.

Comment: That would work to remove exact duplicates, but that's not the case here.

Comment: I see, perhaps @JoMojo could clarify that in the question.

Comment: Also he doesn't just want to remove duplicates, he wants to add up the (partial) duplicates. The question leaves a bit to be desired tbh.

Comment: @MichaelKohl is right on all counts... will be updating my question